How to show a desired part of an image with InteractiveViewer in Flutter?
I am using InteractiveViewer for an image that should be shown in it's original size and panned by user. By default the center part of the image is shown on screen and I want to show another part in the beginning. It's a map and depending on the progress the part of the image that's displayed initially should change. How can I define the part of the image I want to display on screen? Here's the code I'm using:
class GameMap extends StatelessWidget {
  const GameMap({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: InteractiveViewer(
        constrained: false,
        scaleEnabled: true,
        minScale: 0.3,
        maxScale: 1.0,
        child: Image.asset("assets/images/gamemap.jpg",
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

I tried Positioned, but it gives me an error.

Hi you could try something like this
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GameMap extends StatefulWidget {
  const GameMap({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GameMapState createState() => _GameMapState();
}

class _GameMapState extends State<GameMap> {
  final TransformationController _transformationController = TransformationController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Define the initial transformation matrix.
    // Adjust the values here to set the initial part of the image.
    _transformationController.value = Matrix4.identity()
      ..translate(-100.0, -100.0); // Replace these values with the desired initial x and y offsets.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: InteractiveViewer(
        constrained: false,
        scaleEnabled: true,
        minScale: 0.3,
        maxScale: 1.0,
        transformationController: _transformationController,
        child: Image.network("https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/max_1200/e1c5cb28858253.55d5b428f0621.png"),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _transformationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: GameMap(),
  ));
}

try this if it fits you use case.
